# divergence theorem cube question

Tags: vector-analysis

Compute $$\int \int _S F \cdot n \hspace{2mm} dS$$
where $S$ is the surface of the cube bounded by the six planes $$x=0,\hspace{2mm}x=2,\hspace{2mm}y=0,\hspace{2mm}y=4,\hspace{2mm}z=0, \hspace{2mm} z=1$$
$n$ is the outward normal and $$F(x,y,z)=\bigg(y^2-\sin(yz), \frac{\cos(x)}{x^2}-y-z, x^2y+x^2+y^2\bigg)$$

First, this is a cuboid isn't it? Its not a cube, not all the edges are of equal length...

It seems like $div (F)=-1$ so correct me if I am wrong but we can do $$-\int \int \int _V dxdydz$$ which equals the volume of the cuboid right? So the answer is -8?

I feel like I am doing something wrong...

Comment: Yes, it is a cuboid. Aside from the fact $F$ is undefined on the face $x = 0$, your argument is fine.

Comment: So the answer is -8?

Comment: Yup, it should be -8.

Comment: Say if we didn't use the div theorem, and we solve it directly, how many normal would there be? So how many integrals would we have to compute?

Comment: There are six faces and there are six integrals. However, you don't need to compute all of them directly. For example, consider the two faces for $x = 0$ and $x = 2$, Since the $x$ component of $F$ is independent of $x$, the contributions from these two faces cancel. Among these six faces, the only piece that doesn't cancel out is the $-y$ term in the $y$ component of $F$ and it is pretty easy to deal with.